# facebook apprequests redirect on iphone and android

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, apprequests

We have a mobile app (without canvas) on android and iphone. we can send apprequest to the users' friends and the requests appear on their iphone/android phone. We want the iphone users to be redirected to the appstore and the android users to be redirected to the google market. How can we do it?

Comment: Hello Rony, did you get working solution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/:

> *“User to User Requests [/App to User Requests] are only available for Canvas apps […] as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.”*

I guess the only thing that could work in your scenario would be to set up a canvas page for your app, trying to figure out which client platform (iPhone/Android) is used to access it, and then redirect to the appropriate app store page from there …